# How to use External javascript library in typescript - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use Google Login and Jquery in Typescript. I have already made sure that these files are included in the project: jquery.min and an import of google: `<script defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>`

On my component I added:

```
declare var gapi: any;
declare var $: any;
```

But I am still getting an error on `ng serve`:

Cannot find namespace 'gapi'.

How do I properly refer or import external javascript libraries / namespace or functions in Typescript Angular 4?

Comment: ng serve is angular-cli command and related to webpack config initialization. to load external js liblaries you have to use webpack resolvers then import it on your component also you need to define or add its typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install third-party libraries locally, e.g.

```
npm i jquery --save
```

Angular CLI projects have a config file .angular-cli.json. Add jquery to the scripts section there and it'll be available globally for your app, for example:

"scripts": [

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
```

]

It's also a good idea to install type definition files if available. Then you won't need to declare variables of type any, e.g.

```
npm i @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Comment: Will try this out, thanks! But what about javascript libraries that are not on npm? Say, I create myown.js - how do I reference it?

Comment: Then you can use declare as you did. The other choice is to do something like in this code sample (it's not a CLI project though): https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/chapter2/hello-world-ts-jquery